# php compare and fill arrays with different length

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, fill, difference

I have two arrays with different length, containing fields of mysql tables :

```
data1: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => dggd
            [type] => int(11)
            [null] => NO
            [key] => 
            [default] => 
            [extra] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => id2
            [type] => varchar(255)
            [null] => NO
            [key] => PRI
            [default] => 
            [extra] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field] => qwee
            [type] => int(11)
            [null] => NO
            [key] => 
            [default] => 
            [extra] => 
        )

)
 data2: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => id2
            [type] => int(11)
            [null] => NO
            [key] => PRI
            [default] => 
            [extra] => auto_increment
        )
)
```

Basicly I want to fill the array having the less values(with empty records) to match the bigger array's length. Also I want the indexes to match the ['field'] values.

For the upper example I want `data2` after conversion to be like this:

```
data2: Array
(
    [0] => ''
    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => id2
            [type] => int(11)
            [null] => NO
            [key] => PRI
            [default] => 
            [extra] => auto_increment
        )
    [2] => ''
)
```

My code messes everything up, although if you want to see it, here you go https://codeshare.io/ald0pY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template with empty values, based on the `'field'` values in `$data1`.

```
$template = array_fill_keys(array_column($data1, 'field'), '');
```

Reindex `$data2` by its `'field'` values and merge it with the template.

```
$data2 = array_merge($template, array_column($data2, null, 'field'));
```

If you don't want the string keys, convert it back to numeric keys with `array_values`.

```
$data2 = array_values($data2);
```

---

This approach does assume that all values of `'field'` in `$data2` are present in `$data1`. If it has any different `'field'` values, they will be merged onto the end of the template, and the arrays will not be the same length.

Comment: Thanks, it worked pretty well. Btw any idea how to compare `$data1` and `$data2` ? The `==` doesn't work.